# How do I redirect my apache web app from an alias of one domain to a sub domain of another?

Tags: apache2, tomcat, redirect

I have a web application on www.domain1.com where I have installed Apache2 and Tomcat7. I would like to make a redirect from www.domain2.com (which is a www.domain1.com alias) to www.domain1.com:8080/app

What would be the best way to do it?

Comment: Fixed! All I have to do is load proxy and proxy_http module in apache and follow instructions from: http://askubuntu.com/questions/18797/running-apache-and-tomcat-together-on-different-subdomains

Comment: Can you include a answer with instructions on how to do that? [Leaving a half-answer as a comment](http://askubuntu.com/questions/2281/please-stop-posting-half-answers-and-dumb-advice-as-comments) can often cause more harm than good. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

According to the OP:

> Fixed! All I have to do is load proxy and proxy_http module in apache
>   and follow instructions from:
>   [askubuntu.com/questions/18797/…](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18797/running-apache-and-tomcat-together-on-different-subdomains)

– [Carlos Fernández San Millán](/users/35362/carlos-fernandez-san-millan) Apr 9 at 19:14

Solved his problem.